# Matomo, aggregate stats for pages in all subfolders

Tags: matomo

I have an app with identical pages that can be reached by different "groups", so my urls are like :

```
/group1/page1/
/group1/page2/
/group2/page1/
/group2/page2/
```

Is there a way to view the stats for all pages no matter the groupe ?
ie. all stats for "page1" and "page2" ... ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If the page titles are the same, then you should be able to see the reports for the page titles under the `Behaviour > Page titles` report

Alternatively you can set the page title with the Javascript tracker using:

`_paq.push(['setCustomTitle', '']`

You can also use the instructions provided for Single-Page Application tracking in the Developer Docs to set a custom page URL

`_paq.push(['setCustomUrl', '/url/here']);`

You can find more information on setting custom page titles and URLs here: https://developer.matomo.org/guides/spa-tracking